# Rails delete record - param is missing or the value is empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My expense_categories controller:

```
 def delete
       @expense_category = ExpenseCategory.find(params[:id])
    end

  def destroy
     expense_category = ExpenseCategory.find(params[:id]).destroy
     flash[:notice] = "ExpenseCategory '#{expense_category.description}' destroyed successfully."
     redirect_to(expense_categories_path)
    end
```

My delete view:

```
<%= form_for @expense_category do |f| %>
<%= submit_tag("Delete Expense Category", class:"button alert") %>
```

My expense_categories table:

```
class CreateExpenseCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :expense_categories do |t|
      t.string :description

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

My routes:

```
  resources :expenses
  resources :expense_categories

  get ":controller/:action/:id"
```

Whenever I try to delete a record I get

`ActionController::ParameterMissing in ExpenseCategoriesController#update`

```
param is missing or the value is empty: expense_category
```

On page error parameters are

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"patch", "authenticity_token"=>"dWPl0kJaoogDIk1vnTjK8+vvmf7MbI+lzpuRdQ0d6sBZJ+3eFZBk1GdOf+su46d+129niW9wH91YPi9z7PKmaQ==", "commit"=>"Delete Expense Category", "id"=>"1"}
```

Why is expense_category empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ActionController::ParameterMissing in
>   ExpenseCategoriesController#update
>
> param is missing or the value is empty: expense_category

The request is sent to `update` action instead of `destroy` and resulted in that error. You need to specify `method: :delete` to send the request to `destroy` method.

```
<%= form_for @expense_category, method: :delete do |f| %>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That seems to send the request correctly but I now get undefined local variable or method `delete' for #<#<Class:0x0055d02e280920>:0x007fce2824b708>

Comment: I have a view delete.html.erb that calls a partial _form.html.erb. I entered your solution on delete view not in the form.

Comment: @Catmal Sorry, there is a typo. It is `method: :delete`

Comment: Glad to help :) I suggest you to have a look at [`form_for`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for) resource-oriented style to understand this behavior better

Comment: Yes I need to understand clearly why it was sending request to update without specifying the method on form_for. Form_for behavior still confuses me. Thanks again!